# Using rails asset in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm using rails to build a site, and I want to embed a swagger doc in one of the pages. The swagger `yaml` file is stored in `/app/assets/myfile.yaml`. In the swagger embed code (javascript) I've tried a variety of approaches:

```
// in myswagger.html.erb
window.onload = function() {
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "<%= asset_path('myfile.yaml') %>",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ]
    })
}
```

I've also tried a bare path to `/app/assets/myfile.yaml`, `document_path('myfile.yaml')`, etc. But every time we end up with `Fetch error Not Found /swagger.yaml`.
What's the proper way to access this file and get it embedded in the javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fast answer:

put the file yaml in your public folder

otherwise check what is generated at the browser level, by inspecting the page